# Select only one option from 2 dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

Spent 1 day looking for right answer, couldn't find it.

So the problem is I have 2 dropdowns. So what I need is - if the user choosing the option from first dropdown, the second dropdown's choice goes to default and same  with the second dropdown, if the user chooses the option from second dropdowns, the first dropdown goes to default.

Here is the code:

```html
<p>Cars<br /><select style="width: 50%;">
 <option>---</option>
  <option value="volvo" >Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" >Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></p>


<p>Euro<br /><select style="width: 50%;">
 <option>---</option>
  <option value="10">10 Euro</option>
  <option value="20">25 Euro</option>
  <option value="50">50 Euro</option>
  <option value="100">100 Euro</option>
</select></p>
```

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

```js
$(document).on("change", ".selectCar", function(e){
  $('.selectPrice').val('default');
});

$(document).on("change", ".selectPrice", function(e){
    $('.selectCar').val('default');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Cars<br /><select class='selectCar' style="width: 50%;">
 <option value="default">---</option>
  <option value="volvo" >Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" >Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></p>


<p>Euro<br /><select class='selectPrice' style="width: 50%;">
 <option value="default">---</option>
  <option value="10">10 Euro</option>
  <option value="20">25 Euro</option>
  <option value="50">50 Euro</option>
  <option value="100">100 Euro</option>
</select></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Hope it's will be helpful for other users since I checked more than 250 websites yesterday and couldn't find the right answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

HTML

```
 <p>
            Cars<br /><select id="select1" style="width: 50%;">
                <option value="-1">---</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </p>


        <p>
            Euro<br /><select id="select2" style="width: 50%;">
                          <option value="-1">---</option>
        <option value="10">10 Euro</option>
        <option value="20">25 Euro</option>
        <option value="50">50 Euro</option>
        <option value="100">100 Euro</option>
    </select>
        </p>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select1').change(function () {
        var $val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        if ($val != '-1');
        $('#select2').val('-1');
    });
    $('#select2').change(function () {
        var $val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        if ($val != '-1');
        $('#select1').val('-1');
    });
});
```